# What does the asterisk mean in the argument list of scanf

Tags: c, input

I have a gotten a C program, where one of the line having:

```
scanf("%d%*c%d", &x, &y);
```

What is the meaning of `%*c`?

Comment: It means look for a `char` in the input stream but don't save it to any variable.

Comment: [%\*c in scanf() - what does it mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11542010) [scanf() skip variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7607550)

Comment: Neither answer discusses the effect of `*` on the return value of `scanf()`, which I believe is "no contribution".  `scanf("%d%*c%d", &x, &y);` should normally return 2.

Comment: Agreed @chux, `scanf` fields with `*` **are not counted in the return value**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

scanf reads data from stdin and then it stores that data into the parameters pointed according to the format (in your case the parameters are `&x` and `&y`).

`*`indicates that the data is to be read from the stream but ignored (i.e. it is not stored in the location pointed by an parameter).

In your case `%*c` means that the function reads a datatype `char` but does not store it into an instance. It is useful if you want to ignore a part of a string, like the character.

Answer (score 1):

From http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/scanf.html

> ## *
>
> Tells scanf() do to the conversion specified, but not store it anywhere. It simply discards the data as it reads it. This is what you
> use if you want scanf() to eat some data but you don't want to store
> it anywhere; you don't give scanf() an argument for this conversion.
> Example: %*d.